# Memory leak in Java?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I was wondering if the following code produced some sort of memory leak in Java. Anyways here's the code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        a.x = new A(new A(new A(new A(a))));
        a.x.x = null;
    }
}

class A{
    public A x = null;
    A() {}
    A(A a){
        x = a;

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a pretty standard linked list to me. Why would that have a memory leak?

Comment: Are you certain there's a leak? It looks fine. What's making you think where is one?

Comment: There's kind of a leak if you don't want to keep `a.x`.  If you do want to keep it, then it's fine.  Also there's no leak because `a` goes out of scope at the end of the method, and therefore ALL objects you created are eligible for collection, but I don't think that's what you wanted to ask about.

Comment: I made a copy paste error and its supposed to say a.x = new A(new A(new A(new A(a))));

Comment: I was wondering if setting a.x.x to null loses the reference to the other x's within a.x's multiple x's if that makes any sense...

Comment: Yes, and there's no leak.  Java can see there's no reference to the first element you null out, and it knows that therefore any objects that first object refers to "doesn't count."  The Java garbage collector can also find circular references.  `a.x = new A(); a.x.x = a;` can also be collected once `a` goes out of scope.

Comment: how does it deal with circular references like this?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to change your question title to something that is more descriptive and specific. "Memory leak in Java" is not a good title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you number the A's:

```
A a = new A();
//        1
a.x = new A(new A(new A(new A(a))));
//        2     3     4     5
```

Then you have a circular chain:

```
a → 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 1
```

When you break the circle using `a.x.x = null`, you get:

```
a → 1 → 2
```

Instances 3, 4, and 5 are now eligible for garbage collection.

Then, when `main` exits, `a` goes out of scope, and instances 1 and 2 are also eligible for garbage collection.

Note that program will likely end before GC has a chance to do anything.

Comment: Thank you, this response was very instructive and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory leak in that code.

When the `a` variable in `main` goes out of scope, all objects will be unreachable and eligible to be garbage collected.

---

> I was wondering if setting `a.x.x` to `null` loses the reference to the other `x`'s within `a.x`'s multiple `x`'s if that makes any sense...

Not a lot :-)

Proper memory management in Java does not *depend* on things not losing references to other things ... or not.  The overarching rule is that if an object can no longer be reached by any executing code, it cannot influence the computation, and it is *eligible* to be garbage collected.  The GC will deal with an unreachable object as, and when this is necessary ... but generally at the time of its choosing.

Memory leaks in Java actually occur because an object is reachable when you don't want them to be; e.g. when you "hang onto" objects by keeping links to them in a `static` collection.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, and is very clear/informative, thank you!